# Dynamically add and remove attributes in angular directive template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have a directive that builds a div tag used to embed a live preview of information on my webpage. In my directive I have a template that constructs this div tag.

However, I only want the necessary attributes that have been selected on my webpage to be included in the div tag.

In my directive I have:

```
var temp = "<div data-feed class='feed-element' data-num-activities={{numAct.qty}} data-activity-source='{{mySourceSelections[0].SourceId}}' data-activity-actions data-activity-action-social={{socialMediaEmbedSelection()}} data-content-limit={{contentLimit}} data-activity-action-event data-no-activities-message={{noActivitySelection}} id='FeedEmbed'></div>";

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        template: temp
    };
```

Right now, when this div is rendered on my webpage, specific attributes look on the scope to dynamically update fields that are bound by various ng-models (e.g. number of activities, content limit, etc). However, I want to add/remove certain attributes depending on if the user has selected that option to be included at all. For example, data-activity-action-event should not be in the div tag if not selected. How would I do this?

I was thinking to use span and ng-show and ng-hide functionalities but am not sure if that would work since I need to add/remove attributes.

Comment: I also prefer not to use jQuery at all.

Comment: Read up on $scope and ng-model. You could have the attributes selected (checkboxes) to be bound to a data model on the controller or directive.

Comment: All options are currently bound to an ng-model. How would you have those ng-models update inside the template? {{someModel}} is not a valid attribute.

Comment: what does the `data-feed` directive look like?

Comment: The code above is the directive. Has a return statement that provides a template.